# How to load test soap api using jmeter

Tags: java, soap, jmeter

How to load test soap api using jmeter 4.0 , multbinding 
The follow: example for soap request ::

Comment: I use WCF , ?.svc

Answer (score 2):

JMeter naturally supports SOAP protocol, you will need the following Test Elements:

- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler - to send request itself, put your XML payload into the "Body Data" tab

  [image: JMeter HTTP Request for SOAP]
- [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) - to send web-service-specific headers like [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and [`SOAPAction`](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html)

See the following reference material for comprehensive information on web services load testing using JMeter:

- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)
- [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)

Comment: Ok , but return to me response: HTTp/1.1 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

SOAP uses XML payload and POST HTTP method, so as such you can easily test it with  [jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html). 
If you hava abiltiy to capture soap requests, you can save them to CSV files to load it  by JMeter.
Another great load testing look you might take into account is [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk)